# Multiple XMPP login causes loss of messages XMPP framework

Tags: ios, xmppframework, multiple-login

I am working on a chat application that uses multiple xmpp login into the application, so that the user can chat using any of the xmpp login. I have maintained different XMPPStream, XMPPRoster, etc instances in an array. I am able to login with multiple account. The problem, I am facing here is the delegate which receives the presence is called only for one XMPP login at a time which results in loss of messages for the other logins. It seems that at a time only one TCP connections is being maintained. Please let me know what I am missing here.